# Dynamic interfaces list pf.conf

Tags: firewall, bsd, openbsd, vlan

I looking wat to adding passing in/out at interfaces "in fly", first I try just add one by one to anchors by pfctl, but adding next rule clear rule before ;/

```
"pass in on vlanN proto tcp from any to port 22" | sudo pfctl -a vlan_ssh -f -
```

I was try make a table to, but it don't work with interfaces name-s - only ip-s.

```
table <vlan_ssh> = {vlan0, vlan1}
```